# Laravel Excel wrong procedure

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm trying to create a table from xls file with this package for laravel

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Installation of this plugin went, without any problems but it prints nothing.

I know that i'm doing something wrong, but I could't find any simple working example of the script.

```
    $excel = App::make('excel');

    Excel::load('app/example.csv', function($reader) {

        $results = $reader->all();
        return $results;

    });
```

Iven if i would do something like `return 'hello'` it prints nothing...

Do you have any idea why it prints nothing?

Comment: Can't you just use `$results = Excel::load('app/example.csv')->get();`?

Comment: That works fine :) thank your for helping me, post it like a question so I can aproove it :)

Comment: Ok added is as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
$results = Excel::load('app/example.csv')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed using `dump()`or `dd()` method like this
    $reader->dump();
and see if you get anything.Because i dont think that it will print anything if you just return variable.